# random selection from JSON

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I try to convert some JSON string data from JSON object into an array.
When I loop over the JSON is it assign the JSON strings into diffrent array cells, eventually I get all the strings from the JSON but in diffrent order in the array each time I run the program.

```
 for (var i:String in data)
    {
       // get panel tabs and players for each tab
       for (var f:String in data[i].tabs)
        {
          tabsNames.push(f);
            }
    }
```

sometimes tabsNames = [ 1,2,3]
sometimes tabsNames = [ 2,3,1] etc'

I cant use sort because I cant know the type of the information that I will get from the JSON.

Comment: Where did u get JSON string data? Sometimes I get JSON response from Foursquare search and each time in different order.

Comment: I get the same JSON each time. ( I made the JSON )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *JSON object* is an **unordered** set of name/value pairs:

```
"obj" : {"propA" : "valueA", "propB":"valueB"}
```

A *JSON array* is an **ordered** collection of values:

```
"arr" : ["propA":"valueA", "propB":"valueB"]
```

If your data will be stored in JSON Object as list, you always get data in same order.